# Correct Way to Import Git Submodule in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, git-submodules

I have just started using Git for my Xcode projects. I am working on one project, and I have imported another Git repository as a submodule. The files of the submodule are imported into my working copy folder, but what is the correct way to get them into Xcode so I can incorporate them into my code?

Should I import the files? All of them, or only the ones needed? Should I import the entire project folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just import the files needed, if it is a small project.

For larger projects, I try to find ones that build a static library, then you can just drag the project into your projects as a subproject and add the library as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with the static library concept. Looking into it now.